# Enhanced loop for array: if (data[a].contains("word")) issue: incompatible types

Tags: java, arrays, loops, types

homework is to print out a word from a String array. I am using for this the for each loop and the contains() method. 
When I am using the conventional for loop it works. With the enhanced loop I seem to have trouble to get the types straight. 
The error message says incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int

after this worked

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 String[] food = {"appel seed", "apple red", "aple Red", "abelApel"};

 for (int i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
      if (food[i].contains("apple"))
        System.out.println(food[i]);
    }}

//Next, I started to apply the enhanced loop

//food[a] is the use - an integer/String 
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String[] food = {"appel seed", "apple red", "aple Red", "abelApel"};

    for (String a : food) {
      System.out.print(a + " ");
      if (food[a].contains("apple"))
        System.out.println(food[a]);
    }
  }
```

It should print out from the array the words that match "apple":
appel seed 
apple red

Comment: `a` is your `String` value from the food array. Try `if (a.contains("apple"))`. For more details [For-Each Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for (String a : food) ...`
will start a loop with 4 different `a` variables if you like.

therefore change your if-clause to

```
if (a.contains("apple"))
        System.out.println("heureka i found the word: " + a);
```